# How to contribute Part to viewShortCut for "Window->Open View" Menu

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno

I'm creating one RCP in Eclipse juno. In that I created one Part using fragments.
I'm reusing JavaScript perspective.

So I want to add my part in viewShortCut menu , In window->Open View.

In case of eclipse 3.x we have to use `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point and give view ID to contribute in viewShortCut menu.

**Problem:**

So how to contribute eclipse 4 Part to viewShortCut.

All the Part I created through Fragments are not showing even in views (`Window->Open View->Others..`)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is currently no way of contributing MParts to the ShowViewDialog, without using the old extension and compatibility layer. This is not surprising if you have a look at [Bug 323504](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323504).
You will encounter similar problems for example with the perspective switcher. The work ist just not finished in this area, and most Eclipse projects rely heavily on the compatibility layer.

Of course, if you go that way, you will want to create a real MPart, which uses the new features such as dependency injection. This will also make migration later much easier. By using [wrappers such as the DIView](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2011/06/10/how-to-apply-the-e4-programming-model-to-3-x/) you can realize that.

**Update:**
The first milestone of Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) features an 'e4view'-extension point, to integrate MParts into Eclipse 3.x. [This article](http://industrial-tsi-wim.blogspot.de/2013/08/a-giant-leap-for-eclipse-rcp.html) explains in detail how to do this.